# How to prove that $a^{\log_cb}=b^{\log_ca}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I've met a question whereby it asked me to show that $a^{\log_cb}=b^{\log_ca}$. 
I'm okay with the other logarithm questions. But I don't know how to show this question out. Can anyone give some hints or explanation for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take $\log_c$ of both sides.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that for any base $c$
$$a^b = c^{b\log_c a}$$
You can use this here to see that both are equal to
$$c^{\log_c a \log_c b}$$

Answer (score 4):

This follows from $c^{\log_c a\log_c b} = c^{\log_c b\log_c a}$.

Answer (score 3):

Take the $\log_c$ of both sides:
$$
\log_c(a^{\log_cb})\qquad\log_c(b^{\log_ca})
$$
Use the property of the logarithm:
$$
\log_cb\log_ca\qquad\log_ca\log_cb
$$
These are equal, so also the original terms are.